# C++ SEH - correlation between EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION enum and __except() filter expressions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, internals, seh

I'm currently reading about the **Structured Exception Handling** (SEH) mechanism and doing some exercises in C++.

One of the things which I don't understand is -

In `excpt.h` file there are two important definitions "groups":

1. The definition of `EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION` enum and the definition of the `_except_handler` callback function
2. The definition of three macros - `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER` (value is 1), `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH` (value is 0), `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` (value is - 1)

As I understand -

- The values of `EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION` are used when going through the linked list of exception callback function handlers (using `_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION` stuct, pointed to by the Thread Information/Environment Block, pointed to by the `FS` register).
- The values of the three macros are used as `_except` filters

Some of the names of the `EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION` enums have the same names as the three macros mentioned above, but they have absolutely different responsibilities (some are used as `_except` filters and others are used to iterate through a linked list of `_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION`).

**Basically, my question is -** 
What is the reason for this correlation? 
Is there some "intersection" between them? (do they "work" together in some way?)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

The MSVC++ runtime library support for exceptions is built on top of the OS' support for exceptions (SEH). So sure, there is a strong correlation. The OS only wants -1, 0 or 1 to decide what to do next, the macro values are duplicated from the SDK.

Not otherwise a direct match with the enum, that one is returned by the compiler-generated exception filters, generated from the C++ try/catch keywords. The runtime library interprets that value and produces the SEH value. What exactly "nested exception" and "collided unwind" might mean, well, murky.  Not all of the source code is available.  You need to treat it like a pure implementation detail, it does not affect your own code at all.

You only ever use the SEH values in your own __except().

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. Secondly, I'm not sure I've completely understand what you've said regarding the enum. You said that it's returned by the compiler generated exception filters, and that the only time that I need to use it is when I implement my own __except(). It would be great if you could explain that. What I know, is that the EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION is used as a return value of _except_handler (exception callback function) implementations. Thank you.

Comment: I said the *exact* opposite: "You need to treat it like a pure implementation detail, it does not affect your own code at all".  Odd that you did not get that, I can't guess why.  I'll repeat: only use the macro values in your own `__try/__except` code, never the enum.